# SQL Nominal Date Conversion

Tags: sql

I currently have a table with the two columns, one for `Date`, and one for `Datetime`.
These are stored as **nominal values**, and is defined as the **number of days since 12/30/1899**, i.e. `NOM_DATE 0 = 12/30/1899`. **Moment** is defined as the **number of minutes since 12/30/1899 12:00am (GMT**), i.e. `MOMENT 0 = 12/30/1899 12:00am`.

My question is how would I go ahead and convert these into actual dates like dd/mm/yy,
using a stored procedure?

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQ LServer, MySQL, Oracle...

Comment: So datetime also contains the date info?

Comment: THis is using SQl 2005. I should have been more clear, the two columns with nominal dates are int fields. I have to convert the number in the int fields to 12/30/1899 + whatever is in the field. Sounds simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be standard

```
DATEADD(minute, Moment, DATEADD(days, NOM_DATE , '18991230'))
```

This assume `Moment` is for intraday (relative) only (that is, at most 1439).

Edit, after comment

If it is 2 *separate* columns to be converted (is it `NOM_DATE`?)

```
DATEADD(minute, Moment, '18991230')

DATEADD(days, NOM_DATE, '18991230')
```

Comment: Actually, moment is still defined as 12/30/1899 + amount of minutes up to current time and date.

Comment: @Jp: so what has the Date column go to do with it then? it's redundant

Comment: @JP: Are you trying to annoy me. I've given you 2 solution: one where the values are separate, one where cumulative. What do you really want: stop changing your mind

Comment: Seems to be working for me, thanks a lot GBN, you were very helpful!